# 404 Error when opening a link in the “Site Pages” list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am very new SharePoint development and have inherited an existing SharePoint development installation on a VM Ware image. Everything seems to be working correctly with one exception, so far.

When I visit the site and select "Site Actions -> View All Site Content -> Site Pages" I see a list of 6 pages. Two of these pages came with the installation of the SharePoint site ("Home" & "How to Use This Library"). There ae 4 pages there that are custom and were developed by the previous developer. When I click on either of the two that came with the SharePoint Site they open up as expected, however when I attempt to open any of the four new pages I get a 404 Error - "The resource cannot be found".

I am assuming that there is some configuration setting that is missing or incorrectly set. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

-g

Answer (score 1):

More than likely they are still Draft and previous developer never checked them in, which means that there is no approved/published version for you to see.  Try logging in with the System account rather than your own account and you should be able to see them that way.

Comment: I don't think I understand. The "system" account. You don't mean the OS's SYSTEM account do you? I wouldn't know the password for that account. How do I find out if they are in Draft mode or not?

Comment: The System Account is whatever account was used to install the SharePoint farm.  Typically, it is the same account that is used to run the Timer Service or the Central Administration Application Pool

Comment: I found the publish capability under "Site Settings -> Site Content & Structure -> Site Pages" and published the pages but still get a 404 error.

Comment: That most likely means that something is being used by the pages themselves server-side (possibly an image, css or js file) but has not been published as well.  There are sometimes clues to this in your 14/LOGS folder as well

Comment: I think David Wise is right.  The files usually have to be first checked-in and then approved.  You can disable this requirement in the settings, I think.